# TSQL: Rowcounts of All Tables In A Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to obtain the row count of all tables in a server (NOT a particular database, but all the databases on a server, excluding the msdb, model, master, etc).  I don't need any other details to be returned other than the database name, the table name, and row count.

My approach to this problem is to get all the databases in a server and place an id on them, which will be referred to in a while loop (beginning with id one until the maximum id).  Then, within the while loop, I obtain the tables and row counts in the matching database ID.  My problem is that the USE DatabaseName doesn't seem to allow me to make it dynamic, meaning that I can't store a database name in a variable and use it as the referred to database when performing the table with row count query.

Is there another approach to this that I'm missing (I've looked at many other examples - often using cursors, which seem to be much longer in code and appear to use more resources - this is a relatively fast query even if I use the largest database by tables, except that it doesn't hit the next database and so on), or am I missing something obvious in the code to make this dynamic?

```
DECLARE @ServerTable TABLE(
    DatabaseID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    DatabaseName VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @start INT = 1
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')

INSERT INTO @ServerTable (DatabaseName)
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')

WHILE @start < @count
BEGIN

    DECLARE @db VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @db = DatabaseName FROM @ServerTable WHERE DatabaseID = @start

    -- This is the problem, as the USE doesn't seem to allow it to be dynamic.
    USE @db
    GO

    SELECT @db
        ,o.name [Name]
        ,ddps.row_count [Row Count]
    FROM sys.indexes AS i
        INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON i.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps ON i.OBJECT_ID = ddps.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id 
    WHERE i.index_id < 2  AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 
    ORDER BY o.NAME

    SET @start = @start + 1
END
```

Note: I tried checking in the sys.objects and sys.indexes to see if I could filter with a database name, but I had no luck.

**Update:** I tried turning the `SELECT` into something dynamic with no success (note the below code only shows the change `SELECT`):

```
SET @sql = '
    SELECT ' + @db + ' [Database]
        ,o.name [Name]
        ,ddps.row_count [Row Count]
    FROM  ' + @db + '.sys.objects
        INNER JOIN ' + @db + ' sys.objects AS o ON i.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
        INNER JOIN ' + @db + ' sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps ON i.OBJECT_ID = ddps.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id 
    WHERE i.index_id < 2  AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 
    ORDER BY o.NAME'
```

Comment: You need a space before `'[Database]`, you need to also put `' + @db + '` for the two other views, and you also need to execute this string using `EXEC sp_executesql @sql;`. This code currently just creates a string and then does nothing with it. Also, you need to put `DECLARE @db` and `DECLARE @sql` outside of the loop, and you can't say `USE @db` (and you don't need to do that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is essentially the way you do it.

I'm not sure why you think [a while loop is faster than a cursor (though this is a common misconception)](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor). They are essentially the same thing. I don't always use cursors, but when I do, I use `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD` - make sure that you do too. See this article for more info:

- [What impact can different cursor options have?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options)

To reduce the code required for individual tasks like this, you might be interested in the `sp_MSforeachdb` replacement I wrote (`sp_MSforeachdb` is a built-in, undocumented and unsupported stored procedure that will repeat a command for every database, but it is not possible to, say, filter out system databases, and it also has a severe bug where it will sometimes halt execution):

- [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Another way would be dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += '
  SELECT db = N''' + name + '''
    ,o.name [Name]
    ,ddps.row_count [Row Count]
  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.indexes AS i
    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.objects AS o 
      ON i.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps 
      ON i.OBJECT_ID = ddps.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id 
    WHERE i.index_id < 2  AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 
    ORDER BY o.NAME;'
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id > 4;

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

(The print is there so that you can inspect the command before executing. It may be truncated at 8K if you have a large number of databases, but don't be alarmed - that is just a display issue in SSMS, the command is complete.)

You could also build a #temp table first, and insert into that, so that you have a single resultset to work with, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #x(db SYSNAME, o SYSNAME, rc SYSNAME);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += 'INSERT #x(db,o,rc)
  SELECT db = N''' + name + '''
    ,o.name [Name]
    ,ddps.row_count [Row Count]
  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.indexes AS i
    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.objects AS o 
      ON i.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps 
      ON i.OBJECT_ID = ddps.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id 
    WHERE i.index_id < 2  AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 
    ORDER BY o.NAME;'
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id > 4;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT db, o, rc FROM #x ORDER BY db, o;
```

Now, don't be fooled into believing this isn't also using a cursor or loop - it is. But it is building the command in a loop as opposed to executing it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the {WHILE} loop.  I had no idea that it was basically the same thing; I had thought of using dynamic SQL to solve this problem, but I don't know enough about it to troubleshoot it and even when I use the code listed above this, I receive a ton of incorrect syntax errors.

Comment: I tested the code on my own system. Are you sure you've copied it correctly and not made any changes to it? The first one, that just does a print, does it output code you can try to run (maybe one database at a time), or does it not even generate a print? As I said, I've tested both of these on my own system, so I could only explain errors by asking what changed...

Comment: The second code block works; thanks.  I think the reason that my dynamic code failed was because I didn't include QUOTENAME, so it didn't know which database it was.  Also, I'd vote up, but apparently I need 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of you making a dynamic query, rather than use a using, you could do a fully qualified name for your table names, using your selected `@db` variable.

So it would be `'FROM ' + @db+'.sys.objects'` etc.

You would have to check that your DB name is valid (for instance, if you had a name that needed brackets for some reason).

Comment: I updated the post above this to show the dynamic SQL I used (basically, the same SELECT query, using your logic), yet it generates an error related to the SCALAR variable @db.

Comment: *Incorrect syntax near '.'.* Multiple times.  See the OP, I updated the second block of code to show you what I'm running on dynamic SQL.